# jQuery Date picker is not opening on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was messing around with the jQuery Datepicker in the jsFiddle but when I copied the code in my actual project, it's not working. I think the problem is with the jquery CDN. The jsFiddle is using jquery 1.9.1 and jquery UI 1.9.2. I added both of these CDN to my JSP page but it's still not working.

Link to the JS Fiddle: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2gur0y1/4/)

JS File

```
    var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
//    changeMonth: true,
    duration:"slow",
    showAnim: "explode",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    minDate: dateToday,
    maxDate:dateToday+"+2m" ,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    }
});
```

JSP File

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Book A Appointment</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>   
<style type="text/css">
        <%@include file="/CSS/docDetails.css"%>
    </style>
 <script type="text/javascript"
    src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/JS/docDetails.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <span>First Name:</span>${fName }<br> <span>Last Name:</span>${lName }<br>
        <span>Mobile:</span>${mobile }<br> <span>Address:</span>${add }<br>
        <span>Email:</span>${email }<br> <span>Image:</span>${img }<br>
        <span>Speciality In:</span>${special }<br> <span>Degree:</span>${deg }<br>
        <span>Experience:</span>${exp }<br> <span>Fees:</span>${fees }<br>
        <div class="dateBox">
            <input class="js--datePicker" type="text" id="datepicker1"
                value="Date To" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error I am getting.
[image]

CSS File

```
.ui-datepicker {
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 5px auto 0;
  font: 12pt Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.ui-datepicker table {
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-datepicker-header {
  background: #3d3939;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #111;
}

.ui-datepicker-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15pt;
  color: #d9cc3d;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-position: center -30px;
  background-color: white;
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-position: center 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

.ui-datepicker thead {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.ui-datepicker th {
  background-color: #808080;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: red;
}

.ui-datepicker tbody td {
  padding: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
}

.ui-datepicker tbody td:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}

.ui-datepicker tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.ui-datepicker tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.ui-datepicker a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-datepicker td span,
.ui-datepicker td a {
  display: inline-block;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;*/
  /*filter: dropshadow(color=#fff, offx=1, offy=1);*/
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default {
  background: linear-gradient(#999999, #737373);
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;

}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-hover {
  background: #33adff;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active {
  background: #33adff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: #e0e0e0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #4d7a85;
  border: 1px solid #55838f;
  position: relative;
  margin: -1px;
}

.ui-datepicker-unselectable .ui-state-default {
  background: #D6E4BE;
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: @Samanyu Mehra Are you running your `javascript` code which adds the `datapicker` before the `DOM` is loaded?

Comment: @FlashThunder Hi, The JS fiddle that I gave you is the one I picked code from.

Comment: @RyanWilson Hi, Idk anything about DOM or js, I just get the data from my servlet to display it on the JSP file and the rest is in front of you. Sorry I am new in this

Comment: `DOM` stands for `Document Object Model` and `javascript` loads in the order it is presented in the file. So, your code is probably running to add the datepicker before the element you want to add the datepicker to is loaded into the browser. Basically, you are most likely trying to add a datepicker to an element which does not exist yet. You can try the provided answer below to see if that helps. You can read more about what the `DOM` is here: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

Comment: Thanks, @RyanWilson I will read that but I want you to know that the guy who answered below suggested me to write the js file at the bottom of the JSP file, and then it was working but there was this div which is loading now at the reload of the page. I checked it on chrome dev console and I found out that this is getting added when this page is loaded. <div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>

Comment: Hello @RyanWilson I have added the image of the error in my question please check it out.

Comment: That isn't an error, `jqeury's` `datepicker` adds that to the `DOM`, it's the little datepicker widget. This happens on the call to `datepicker()`. This is intended behavior, without it, you wouldn't have the graphical representation of the calendar to pick from.

Comment: So how can I get rid of that? When I was doing this in jsFiddle nothing was happening. But nevermind please guide me on how to get rid of this

Comment: You don't want to get rid of it. Without it, you can't get the calendar widget.

Comment: So then how can i hide it cuz I need to hide that, I cant leave it like that right?

Comment: yeah, I know it will disappear after the user clicks on that but still I have to hide it and I don't know how to do that. PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: No @RyanWilson, See the image that I showed to you. It's not hidden until the user focuses on it. When I reload the page that div is added and It is not hidden. Refer to the image. That's the photo when I reload the page and that's the first thing that happens without clicking anywhere

Comment: Whenever I reload the page, that div is there. You can refer to the image for that and i want to hide it cuz user can see it when it gets to this page

Comment: I just copied the js code from the fiddle and I added CSS from another person. I think that might be the issue. Should I post the CSS code too?

Comment: @SamanyaMehra You should post anything relevant to your problem, ie. your `CSS` may be a part of the problem. I can't say without seeing it.

Comment: Okay wait i am adding my css file also

Comment: @RyanWilson i added my css file also. Please check it out

Comment: I did it haha Thanks Buddy. I hide the div with the id in my css file. THANKS @RyanWilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your script file at the bottom of document, the error is the dom not ready when you call to the function script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Book A Appointment</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>   
    <style type="text/css">
        <%@include file="/CSS/docDetails.css"%>
    </style>

 </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <span>First Name:</span>${fName }<br> <span>Last Name:</span>${lName }<br>
        <span>Mobile:</span>${mobile }<br> <span>Address:</span>${add }<br>
        <span>Email:</span>${email }<br> <span>Image:</span>${img }<br>
        <span>Speciality In:</span>${special }<br> <span>Degree:</span>${deg }<br>
        <span>Experience:</span>${exp }<br> <span>Fees:</span>${fees }<br>
        <div class="dateBox">
            <input class="js--datePicker a" type="text" id="datepicker1"
                value="Date To" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
        
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var dateToday = new Date();
        console.log($("#datepicker1"))
        var dates = $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        //    changeMonth: true,
            duration:"slow",
            showAnim: "explode",
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            minDate: dateToday,
            maxDate:dateToday+"+2m" ,
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I did what you said and a weird div is being displayed. I checked it on chrome dev console and I found out that this is getting added when this page is loaded.
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>

Comment: Is there any way to link a js file and work around with that and then do it cuz I want to do it that way?

Comment: I copied the code in the js file and did the same thing. I added at the bottom of the code but still the same error

Comment: Hey @Luis Romero, I have added the image of the error in my question please check it out.

Comment: are you link the css file in stylesheet?